# Eliminating duplicate code from Cacscading Style Sheet

Tags: css

I am building a website and when it is about to finish I realized it's a mess. The mistake I did was that I forgot to label individual parts of the code i.e. "Navbar Code below" and adding an ending point. Moreover when debugging the code I wrote the code on screen, where I found some empty spaces rather than being organized and writing in designated place. This leads to example below:

```
/*Navbar Started*/
    nav a{
        margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    }
```

Followed by somewhere deep down below in the code:

```
#a1{
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Where #a1 is a link in nav, so above margin is over-ruled. This is the most simplest example.
Is there any app or code which can find duplicate lines in my code and organize them by either deleting them or adding all properties at one place i.e.

```
#a1{
    margin:5px;
}
And having this code somewhere down:
#a1{
    padding:5px;
}
```

It should give the following output:

```
#a1{
    margin:5px;    
    padding:5px;
}
```

I know I have done wrong but I have to get the code organized and I know manually doing it would take heck a lot of time.

```
If no piece of code exists, please let me know. 
I know python well and would try to make a code and upload it on Github to help Novice developers like myself. 
Any commitment on helping in the development of that code would be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: you can try with purgeCSS https://purgecss.com/CLI.html for the css unused

Comment: PurgeCSS is great for frameworks as the website mentions. Moreover it finds unused selectors so not helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Visual Studio Code you can install the plugin named DupChecker**

Here are the steps to install and find the duplicated CSS classes:

Go to extensions tab (Ctrl + Shift+ X).

Search with “DupChecker” and install it.

Go to the CSS file.

Type (Ctrl + Shift + P) and search with “check duplicates with regex match” and select it.

Paste this regex ^.[\w-\s.>:,[]*=]+{ and hit Enter.

**Note**: Among the results, there can be shown concatenated classes as duplicated ones. Be careful while removing the classes.

Comment: Thx but it is not working.
I copied a part of my code in the file and the output was:
⚙️[trimStart] [trimEnd]
✅0 duplicate value found in 513 lines:
While having a _duplicate_ in front of me.
I used this regex "**^.[\w-\s.>:,[]*=]+{**".(In the double quotes)
Maybe a problem with regex.